# Updating/editing localStorage - JSONObject

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Is it possible to edit a JSON object stored on web local storage? Currently I have a stringified JSON object

`{fname":"Jerry","lname":"Lewis","email":"Jlewis@hollywood.com","password":"*********"}`

using the function

`localStorage.setItem()` to save.

How can I make changes to the above ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("yourKey"));
myObj.fname = "Clyde"; //change fname to Clyde
localStorage.setItem("yourKey", JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

Comment: Perfect! But what if I want to add for example a telephone number to the object ?

Comment: @user2678538 -- Add it `myObj.telephone = number` restringify and save

Comment: Ok so using dot notation basically works for both existing and non existing attributes! Thanks a heaps