# Performance of edits to localStorage with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, serialization, local-storage, web-storage

According to the [W3 Web Storage specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-storage-interface), values in localStorage are of type string.

Thus, an entry can't be granularly updated like a subproperty of a JS object and it's only possible to replace the entire key:

[Updating/editing localStorage - JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135511/updating-editing-localstorage-jsonobject)

Assume I want to "secure" user input frequently on the client side in the localStorage, and also update it on model changes on the server (only transmitting changes from server to client). **How often can I `JSON.stringify()` my local data (=ViewModel state) and save it to the localStorage without causing trouble for the user?** Is serializing and saving (not transmitting!) e.g. 30KB of data every 5 seconds to the localStorage going to cause lags?

Bonus question: Does any major browser vendor plan on storing JS objects directly in localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be entirely true; there is a method for updating a single key to an object housed in local storage, and the code is below.

```
var updateLocalStorageKey = function(obj, key, val) {

  var localObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[obj] )

  localObj[key] = val;

  //reset storage

  localStorage[obj] = JSON.stringify(localObj)
}
```

The working jsbin is here: http://jsbin.com/jesapifa/4/edit?html,js,output

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks, but it basically deserializes JSON to JS object, changes an element and serializes to JSON again. That is pretty inefficient, as my ViewModel holds the data as JS object for direct manipulation - I can avoid the JSON parsing and directly stringify my object and overwrite the localStorage key.