# How to edit Array data in localstorage in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form. I've already stored the array data in localStorage by using `localStorage.setItem('x', x)`.

But how to edit or delete such values in `localStorage`?

Comment: You can see here all methods of [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage).

Comment: can u just give an little example to use it in React js, for Editing an object in local storage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating/editing localStorage - JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135511/updating-editing-localstorage-jsonobject)

Comment: You can check this post to see examples with `reactjs` [Session Storage and Local Storage in React](https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react/) @Jayakar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set Item / Update item**

> localStorage.setItem('key', value);

**Read item**

> var data = localStorage.getItem('key');

**Delete item**

> localStorage.removeItem('key');

**Delete all items**

> localStorage.clear();

**To store JSON object**

```
    var data = {
       name:'john',
       age:20
    }

    localStorage.setItem('data',JSON.stringify(data));

    // To get data back

    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));

   // Editing data

   data.name = 'mark';

  // Saving Back

  localStorage.setItem('data',JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: i think that, these are for single value. But can i know how to store, edit and delete an object in LocalStorage, @Banujan Balendrakumar

Answer (score 0):

For editing just rewrite original property

```
localStorage.hello   = "Hello World";
localStorage.hello   = "Hello World. Part 2.";
localStorage.getItem("hello") // "Hello World. Part 2.";
```

For deleting

```
localStorage.removeItem("hello");
```